# Ruby on Rails each do method.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I am having difficulty with a ruby method on my show page. I have two models: events, and payments. I am trying to show all payments made to a particular event.

I used this method on my show page on my events model and I was able to show the payments in array format like this ($1000 $4000 $2000)

```
<strong>Payments Made: </strong>
  <% @event.payments.each do |p| %>
    $<%= p.Payment_amount.to_s.reverse.gsub(/...(?=.)/,'\&,').reverse %>
  <% end %>
```

What I would like is to show the payments like this:

Payment 1: $1000
Payment 2: $4000
Payment 3: $2000

I appreciate the help. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Does `Payment_amount` a method ?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like `Payment_amount` is a column and available as a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another method that is similar to `.each`, except it also includes the index value at each iteration. It is called [`each_with_index`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index). You can use it in your scenario like so:

```
<% @event.payments.each_with_index do |payment, index| %>
  Payment <%= index + 1%>: $<%= payment.Payment_amount.to_s.reverse.gsub(/...(?=.)/,'\&,').reverse %>
<% end %>
```

*Note the `index + 1`, since arrays are zero-based, and therefore the first payment will be index 0.*

Comment: @Liliana Awesome, glad you got it working. Don't forget to accept an answer, whichever one best answers the question (green checkmark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<strong>Payments Made: </strong>
<% @event.payments.each_with_index do |p, i| %>
  Payment <%= i+1 %>: $<%= p.Payment_amount.to_s.reverse.gsub(/...(?=.)/,'\&,').reverse %>
<% end %>
```